# Создание динамического двумерного массива для хранения строк

Tags: c++

Упражнение 1.17. Напишите программу печати всех вводимых строк, содержащих более 80 символов.

Вводятся символы с консоли. Не могу понять, как задать массив, у которого будет строка состоять из введённых символов и в нём же чтоб считалось количество этих строк. Более того, как будет выглядеть вывод этого массива?

Answer (score 3):

Если нужна строка - используете `char *`, `char [SOME_CONST]` или [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) (последнее предпочтительно, т.к. это специализированный класс строк, поэтому меньше вероятность нарваться на проблемы с памятью)

Если нужен массив строк (действительно нужен) - или указатель на указатель, или `std::vector<std::string>` (желательно). Для прохода по вектору придется использовать итераторы. Это не так страшно, как звучит.

Ввод строчек с клавиатуры можно сделать множеством способов. Начиная от посимвольного, кончая построчным. Нормальными выглядят варианты с использованием [`scanf("%s", pointer_to_char_arr)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/), [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/), [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) или [`cin::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/). Короче, способов масса. Следует обратить особое внимание за не выход за границы буферов и аккуратно работать с указателями (если будете их использовать).

Comment: P.S. если непонятно - спрашивайте, попытаемся разобраться вместе.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения данной задачи массивы не нужны !!!

Алгоритм:

Читаете строку за строкой. Если длина строки больше 80 , печатаете ее. По концу ввода заканчиваете программу.

Все.

Comment: Ну а как мне задать этот динамический массив то? Алгоритм есть, а вот массива стринг нет...

Comment: Повторяю, МАССИВ СТРОК НЕ НУЖЕН !!!! 

Достаточно одной строки (если изучить матчасть, то хватит 82-х символов (с учетом завершающего строку нуля)).

Comment: Боюсь, Вы неверно поняли задачу. Изначально у нас вводятся строки. А выводятся они в конце работу программы. Т.е. выглядит это так:

<pre>Ввод данных:
str1
str2
str3
....
Среди введенных строк имеются следующие строки с кол-вом символов > 80:
abcdef....
abcdef1....</pre>

Про блокировку отображения введенных символов ни слова.

Comment: мне для каждой строки создавать str1 str2 str3 ?
или можно задать массив который будет эти строки хранить? можно пример пожалст.

Comment: ПРИМЕРНО так:
<pre>
   std::vector<std::string> str_array;
   while (...)                  // условие окончания цикла придумайте сами
   {
     std::string my;            // определили временную переменную строки
     std::cin.getline(my, 256); // положим строчки более 256 символов не будут
     str_array.push_back(my);   // засунули очередную строку в вектор
   }
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter; // итератор
   for (iter = str_array.begin();
        iter != str_array.end();
        ++iter )
     std::cout << *iter << std::endl; // вывести очередную строчку на экран</pre>

Comment: А как еще можно понять такую формулировку вопроса ? Ведь ни слова о том, что вывод в конце.